# Is every atom of this universe a representation of Maha Vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, philosophy, gaudiya-vaishnavism

According to Gaudiya Vaishnavism, The material world is made from the expansion of Maha-Vishnu, means whatever material was made from his body.

Does each and every atom of this universe is a representation of Mahavishnu?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he is in every atom

Bhagavata Purana Canto 11-Chapter 16-Shloka 39

> Even though over a period of time I might count all the atoms of the
>   universe, I could not count all of My opulences which I manifest
>   within innumerable universes
>
> Purport: The Lord here explains that Uddhava should not expect a
>   complete catalog of the Lord’s opulences, since even the Lord Himself
>   finds no limit to such opulences. According to Srila Jiva Gosvami,
>   kalena indicates that the Supreme Personality of Godhead is within
>   every atom and can therefore easily calculate the total number of
>   atoms. However, although the Lord is certainly omniscient, even He
>   Himself cannot supply a finite number for His opulences, because they
>   are infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Every living thing has a starting point. Consequently, every atom also has a starting point. Atoms are the remnants of the paramatma in mortal form. It is therefore expected that every thing, whether living or non living must be respected.